# Task cancellation with LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler and Task.Start vs TaskFactory.StartNew

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I use [`LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.100).aspx). And I don't understand why task cancellation works in different ways when tasks are created by `Task` constructor in one case and by `TaskFactory.StartNew()` in another.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action longAction =
            () =>
            {
                Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Long action is finished.");
            };
        Action actionToBeCanceled = () => Console.WriteLine("Never see this");

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        // only one task can be running at once
        TaskScheduler lclts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(1);

        // case A
        Task longTask = new Task(longAction, CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskCreationOptions.None);
        Task taskToBeCanceled = new Task(actionToBeCanceled, cts.Token, 
            TaskCreationOptions.None);
        longTask.Start(lclts);
        taskToBeCanceled.Start(lclts);

        // case B
        //TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(lclts);
        //Task longTask = factory.StartNew(longAction);
        //Task taskToBeCanceled = factory.StartNew(actionToBeCanceled, cts.Token);

        taskToBeCanceled.ContinueWith(
            t => Console.WriteLine("taskToBeCanceled is completed. Status=" + t.Status),
            CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

        Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("After cancel. Status=" + taskToBeCanceled.Status);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output in case A:

```
After cancel. Status=Canceled
taskToBeCanceled is completed. Status=Canceled
Long action is finished.
```

Output in case B:

```
After cancel. Status=WaitingToRun
Long action is finished.
taskToBeCanceled is completed. Status=Canceled
```

In case A `taskToBeCanceled` is canceled right after `cts.Cancel()`. But in case B it is canceled after `longTask` is completed. How does it work? Something invokes `TaskScheduler.TryDequeue()` in case A. But why doesn't it happen with `TaskFactory.StartNew`? What should I do (using `TaskFactory.StartNew`) to make task to be canceled right after `cts.Cancel`?

Comment: All credit due for a good [mcve] showing what you're asking. I may not find the question _useful_, but it is at least _clear_. :) That said, it seems to me your question essentially involves asking why a particular implementation detail is the way it is. Nothing in the documentation makes any promises regarding order of task execution or cancellation. So either behavior is "fine". Likely it comes down to optimizations which exist in `StartNew()` which aren't possible in `Start()` (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/06/13/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/).

Comment: Interestingly, [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) by the same author implies that a task will be transitioned to cancelled in your scenario, but that said, they don't say _when_ that will happen, just that it does.

Comment: Do not use the `Task` constructor. Do not use `.Wait` on task, use `await`. Your code is a mix from sync and async methods.

Comment: @Peter Duniho thank you for the attention and the articles. I've read them before. But yes, my goal is to realize when does the cancellation remove scheduled tasks from the `TaskScheduler`. Behaviour with `TaskFactory.StartNew` is not what I expected.

Comment: @VMAtm thanks for the advice. `Wait()` here is just for imitation of CPU-bound work. I don't do this in real code. If I used `await Task.Delay()` in this example the second Task would start before finish of first one.

Comment: TaskScheduler do not remove tasks from itself. Tasks are the ones who should deal with cancellation.